# Adding in derived data to an SQL view

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a view that has the following columns; "guid" and "is_clinician". The view pulls from two tables, "resource" and "clinician". Basically what I want is for the "is_clinician" column to just record which table the guid came from. Is this possible, or will I have to change my data flow?

Comment: Post the view definition please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the resouce will only exist in one table or the other, then something like this:

```
SELECT guid, 'y' as is_clinician
FROM tableA

UNION ALL

SELECT guid, 'n' 
FROM tableB
```